# Получить строку по регулярному выражению

Tags: bash

В скрипте есть переменная со строкой:

```
"-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1702 2015-01-01 00001_file.txt"
```

нужно вытащить из нее дату и имя файла.

Дату пытаюсь получить с помощью регулярного выражения

```
"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"
```

имя файла также буду вытягивать через регулярку. Пытался через `expr` - не выходит:

```
expr "-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1702 2015-01-01 00001_file.txt" : '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/'
```

Что я делаю не так? Может быть, есть более удобная команда?

Comment: так впишите руками нужное. если это всего одна строка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
STR="-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1702 2015-01-01 00001_file.txt";
WORD1=`echo ${STR} | awk '{print $6}'`;
echo $WORD1
```

как то так имя файла $7.

Comment: В принципе хороший вариант, но может все же есть возможность через регулярки?

Comment: @ОлегС, регулярные выражения bash поддерживает только в правой части оператора `=~` (см. `man bash`).

Answer (score 0):

если такая строка всего одна и заранее известна, то проще вырезать нужные символы по их позициям (если по каким-то причинам не подходит простое копирование-вставка):

```
$ stroka="-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1702 2015-01-01 00001_file.txt"
$ data=${stroka:28:10}
$ imja=${stroka:39}
```

---

### обновление

как оказалось, строк таких «очень много». если количество полей во всех этих строках стабильно (шестое поле — дата, седьмое поле — имя), то, ограничиваясь лишь встроенными средствами программы *bash*, можно воспользоваться одной из форм *heredoc*:

```
$ stroka="-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1702 2015-01-01 00001_file.txt"
$ read a a a a a data imja <<< "$stroka"
$ echo $data
2015-01-01
$ echo $imja
00001_file.txt
```

переменная `a` здесь использована для «вбирания в себя» пяти первых ненужных полей.

Comment: Строк очень много(

Comment: в тексте вопроса вы написали ровно противоположное. тогда надо озвучивать чёткие критерии. а ещё лучше — брать нужные значения (дату и имя) ещё **до** попадания их в «одну переменную».

Comment: @ОлегС, я обновил ответ.

Comment: Благодарю! Брать дату до - никак не выйдет :( А вот что касается стабильности, то не всегда так - дата то 6, то 5.

Comment: Думаю, мне будет достаточно разбиения строки на переменные.

Answer (score 0):

Если цель использования регулярок чер ls чтоб просто вытащиь дату обновления файла, то не проще ли сразу через find указать маску вывода?

```
~$ find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%p %AY-%Am-%Ad\n"
```

Если этот в скрипте скормите строку grep с ключами -o и -P

```
STRING="-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1702 2015-01-01 00001_file.txt"

echo "$STRING" | grep -oP "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"
```

GNU findutils

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/find
- https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Time-Formats

GNU grep

- https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Regular-Expressions